# NSString initWithFormat memory leak stumper

Tags: objective-c, xcode

XCode is suggesting that an `[NSString initWithFormat]` method (as listed in the Instruments window) is the source of a memory leak. It lists the particular method, so in that method I identified the only line of code with `initWithFormat` (as unlike some leaks identified in Instruments, this one will not take me to the exact offending line of code for some reason):

```
 NSString * name=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[lineArray objectAtIndex:0] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] ];

 CustomObject * newData=[[CustomObject alloc] init];
 newData.info=name; // info is a retained NSString ivar of CustomObject

 [name release];
 [self.ivar setObject:newData forKey:@"key"];
 [newData release];
```

The `initWithFormat` and the `release` are within the same scope: both occur inside an `if` statement.

Are there some NSString methods that somehow call `initWithFormat` without it being obvious in the code? Such as these `stringByTrimmingcharactersInSet` type methods?

UPDATE: I've added all the code between the `initWithFormat` and the `release` -- Also, even if I change `initWithFormat` to `stringWithFormat`, Xcode gives me the same memory leak, instead identifying `stringWithFormat`, so this is clearly the object causing the problem.

Comment: This code you posted looks fine, there has to be some intermediate code causing the problem. You might want to expand your code sample to show what you are doing with the `name` variable, in-between its allocation and release.

Comment: Perhaps it does take you to the exact offending line of code, but you don't recognize it as such? Show that exact offending line, please.

Comment: it is not taking me to any source code at all. using the Call Tree, I can track down where the method is, and I further confirmed this by changing it to stringWithFormat, and this caused the Call Tree to change the leak to the stringWithFormat method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instruments doesn't show where the object was leaked; it shows where the object that was leaked was *created*.  So what's probably going on is you're not releasing the `info` ivar of your `CustomObject` class in its `dealloc` method.  Either that, or you're over-retaining that object somewhere else.

Comment: ah, thank you! the `dealloc` was the missing link here. i simply forgot to add it there. cheers.